# change justified text size to div automatically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been using https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js that to try and recreate this effect https://i.stack.imgur.com/EyWMz.png. Basically, I would like every word and phrase inside of a `div` to automatically increase/decrease in size to fit the `div`'s width.

I've had problems with line breaks and text not filling the div completely, and longer words hanging outside the boundary of the `div` instead of nesting perfectly inside. For example, The line "Sean Connery" will look like

Sean

Connery

instead of

#Sean#
Connery

Where the width of the column is equal to the word "Connery". Is there a way to fix this? I know I could do it by hand, but that is tedious and I'm going to be doing a lot of these newspaper style headlines in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently and I started with FitText.js too. I ended up making my own and it was quite easy.

In your code:

- create a test container that the browser will render but not display because you position it off-screen
- then you add the text to the test container and increment the text-size until the text makes the container larger than desired.

You'll need to give a short break between changing text-sizes so the browser can render the change. I did this by running my code in a loop that called a `setTimeout` recursively until a large enough text-size is found.

Comment: thanks for the reply! unfortunately i've forgotten all of my javascript (would you even make it in javascript?)  and have no idea how to code something like that. do you have an example i could look at??